# Error when redirecting after login in Django 1.2

Tags: django, django-urls

I've been getting this error:

> The requested admin page does not exist.

I've got a view at the URL `/members/` which is protected by `@login_required`. When I'm not logged-in and visit the `/members/` URL, I get redirected to:

> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/members/`

When I enter my login credentials and click "Log in", I get that error (only when `DEBUG` is `True`, otherwise I get a 404), and I'm still at the address:

> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/login/?next=/members/`

Some comments I've found about this seem to be to do with the order in which I add bits to my `urlpatterns`, but that doesn't seem to make any difference.

Any other ideas?

My `urls.py` looks roughly like this:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^$', 'myproject.views.homepage', {}, 'homepage'),
    # some other stuff
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^members/', include('members.urls', namespace = u'members', app_name = u'members')),
)

urlpatterns += patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)), 
)
```

Let me know if there's anything else that might help me work out what's wrong!

Comment: Is there a reason why your user login URL is the same as the admin app's login URL? Is this by design?

Comment: @Manoj - Originally there was only the admin app that needed a login. This is my first foray on this project into non-admin login_required views. I will move this soonish - could this be causing the problem?

Comment: @dominic: Looks like that is the case, though I don't know the details. I tried it out in one of my projects `http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/valid_url/` and got the same error.

Comment: @Manoj - that works - can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason why your user login URL is the same as the admin app's login URL? Is this by design?

> Originally there was only the admin app that needed a login. This is my first foray on this project into non-admin login_required views. I will move this soonish - could this be causing the problem?

Looks like that is the case, though I don't know the details. I tried it out in one of my projects `http://localhost:8000/admin/login/?next=/valid_url/` and got the same error.

Solution: use a different view for user login.